# Como devo testar um repositorio EF core com xunit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Actualmente estou a testar um repositorio da seguinte forma:

```
public class SomethingTest
{
    [Fact]
    public async void GetKeyValuesAsync_NotNull()
    {

        // Arrange
        var categoryRepository = CreateRepository();
        var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        var categoryModel = fixture.Build<Category>()
                        .Without(x => x.Property)
                        .Create();

        // Act
        var categoryCreated = await categoryRepository.CreateAsync(categoryModel);
        var result = await categoryRepository.GetKeyValuesAsync();

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
    }

    private CategoryRepository CreateRepository()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddDbContext<TokensContext>(x => { x.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "StoreMemoryContext", new InMemoryDatabaseRoot()); });
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var mockLocalizationService = new Mock<ILocalizationService>();
        var mockNormalizationService = new Mock<INormalizationService>();
        var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<CategoryRepository>>();
        return new CategoryRepository(serviceProvider,
                                    mockLocalizationService.Object,
                                    mockNormalizationService.Object,
                                    mockLogger.Object);


    }
}
```

Eu acredito que a forma como estou do provider sql para UseInMemoryDatabase não é a mais correcta, mas não sei como consigo alterar de outra forma

O que parece estar acontecer é que estou ali a criar um mock do IServiceProvider mas internamente o EF esta a usar outro IServiceProvider consigo usa apenas um sabendo que tenho de o passa no construtor da class CategoryRepository o parametro IServiceProvider ?

> Error generated for warning
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ManyServiceProvidersCreatedWarning':
> More than twenty 'IServiceProvider' instances have been created for
> internal use by Entity Framework. This is commonly caused by injection
> of a new singleton service instance into every DbContext instance. For
> example, calling UseLoggerFactory passing in a new instance each
> time--see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869049 for more
> details. Consider reviewing calls on 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' that
> may require new service providers to be built. This exception can be
> suppressed or logged by passing event ID
> 'CoreEventId.ManyServiceProvidersCreatedWarning' to the
> 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
> 'AddDbContext'.

Comment: *"UseInMemoryDatabase não é a mair correcta"* essa é a forma mais simples de resolver isso e é muito usada, mas talvez o melhor seria separar o EF da implementação, por isso num Repository por exemplo, ai seria fácil injetar um mock do Repository para os testes :) Se o projeto estiver no início seria ótimo separar a dependência com um Repository

Comment: @RicardoPontual na verdade esta separado essa class CategoryRepository é onde tem a implementação

Comment: então nem precisa fazer mock do DBcontext mas dos método do CategoryRepository faz um `var mockRepo = new Mock<ICategoryRepository>()` e depois `mockRepo.Setup(s => s.NomeMetodo...).Returns(categoryModel)`. Agora se quiser testar o Repository ai não tem jeito, melhor usar um inMemory

Comment: acho que o que está ali a acontecer é que estou ali a criar um mock do IServiceProvider mas internamente o EF esta a usar outro IServiceProvider consigo usa apenas um sabendo que tenho de o passa no construtor da class CategoryRepository?